# Intelij says : Checks if Spring MVC View references are resolved correctly

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, model-view-controller

[image: It seems the folder webapp is not visible from WebConfig.java]
The version of Intelij is 2017.3 Ultimate Edition.
Pls give advice where to dig?

Comment: Have you actually tested the application? Make sure it isn't a false positive warning.

Comment: Yes, i did. Before i tested the same project  on the other, remote  PC . It worked. But now on the this remote PC the same situation.  Both PC are Linux stations. Intelij 2018 Ultimate on the remote PC

Comment: Btw, I created new project as Maven project using maven-archetype-webapp.

Comment: Did you actually run the project?

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Comment: So then it is a false positive in Intellij.

Comment: Make sure you have configured Spring context https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html#configure-spring-project-facet Also could this with 2018.3 from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download and if you still see the issue file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: Intelij support team adviced to replace in method configureViewResolvers :

instead of 
         registry.jsp().prefix("/WEB-INF/views/").suffix(".jsp");

should be
         registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/",".jsp");

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001943999-Intelij-says-Checks-if-Spring-MVC-View-references-are-resolved-correctly?page=1#community_comment_360000285779